# Change UIView frame using constraint autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to change the UIView's frame using autolayout constraint. I can adjust the position, but can't adjust the size.

Is there any way to change the frame and position according to screen resolution ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Add your work done.

Comment: Update the question with the code.

Comment: @Anton Volkov you need to increse view size with device size?

Comment: With autolayout you can give a view proportional width and height (programmatically or from the storyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Intrinsic Content Size`

Please look this [AutoLayout User experience](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1)

Answer (score 3):

For example you can do this.

```
    yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Position
    yourView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
    yourView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true

    // Height and width
    yourView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    yourView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```